# Rails 4 Left outer join multiple tables with Group By and count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Is it possible to do a left outer join in Rails4 with group by and counts. I am trying to write a scope which will do a left outer join of users with the messages, comments and likes tables and then group by id to get total count. In case there is no association, the count should be zero.

So the final result set would be cuuser.*, message_count, likes_count and comments_count. Any idea how this can be accomplished? Thanks in Advance!

```
class Cuuser < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
    has_many :messages
    has_many :comments
    has_many :likes

    validates :username, format: { without: /\s/ }
    scope :superusers, -> { joins(:comments, :likes).
        select('cuusers.id').
        group('cuusers.id').
        having('count(comments.id) + count(likes.id) > 2')}
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could drop to SQL strings:

```
joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN comments ON comments.cuuser_id = cuuser.id LEFT OUTER JOIN likes ON likes.cuuser_id = cuuser.id LEFT OUTER JOIN messages on messages.cuuser_id = cuuser.id")
```

This isn't great. You're sacrificing some portability and the ability of ActiveRecord to guess the association.

If you used the Squeel gem you could use the following format:

```
joins{ [comments.outer, likes.outer, messages.outer] }
```

Squeel exposes Arel in a slightly more sane format, so you can do things like left outer joins while still guessing associations from the model definitions.

You could use Arel of course, but things get very clunky very quickly.

To get your counts, try:

```
select('cuusers.id, count(messages.id) as message_count, count(likes.id) as likes_count, count(comments.id) as comments_count').
```

They should be available as attributes on the returned objects, just like ordinary database fields.

Comment: Thanks Trying this now. Any idea how to show zero as the message_count in case the left outer join association is null

Comment: Updated. I don't think you need to do that with counts.

Comment: Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/users/1448966/a-fader-darkly. It gives the right query. However in the output, there is only the id which shows up, not the counts .

The output and scope are here https://gist.github.com/ganeshran/d02cf5b3a0e5cd81978d

Comment: Never mind. It was a brainfreeze .. Wrong spelling in model. Thanks for your help